# Трудности в Bootstrap верстке

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Есть страница, внутри нее есть .
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Додумался только до этого:

```
<style>
.spisoc {
    color: #ffffff; font-size: 18px; font-family: arial, sans-serif; margin-left: -30px;
}
.adress {
    color: #ffffff; font-size: 18px; font-family: arial, sans-serif;
}
@media (min-width: 1360px){
    .container {
        width: 1360px;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 1910px){
    .container {
        width: 1920px;
    }
    .main_logo {
        margin-left: 68px;
    }
    .top_credits_1 {
        margin-right: 63px;
    }
    .top_credits_2 {
        margin-right: 63px;
    }
    .logo_title_1 {
        font-size: 72px;
    }
    .logo_title_2 {
        font-size: 48px;
    }
    .logo_text_1 {
        margin-top: 60px;
    }
    .logo_text_2 {
        margin-top: -25px;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 1366px){
    .logo_title_1 {
        width: 1900px;
    }}
@media (max-width: 1366px){
    .main_logo {
        margin-left: 0px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 1920px){
    .top_wood{

        height: 295px;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 1400px){
    .logo_title_1 {
        font-size: 48px;
    }
    .logo_title_2 {
        font-size: 36px;
    }
    .logo_text_1 {
        margin-top: 69px;
    }
}
.container {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}
</style>
<div class="top_layer"  style="width: 100%;  background: #606c75;">
<div style="padding-top: 35px; padding-bottom:35px; text-align: center">
<span style="text-align: center; color: #ffffff; font-size: 36px; font-  family: arial, sans-serif;" >ВОЗМОЖНОСТИ</span>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="container" style="">
        <div class="col-md-2" style="text-align: left;">
            <img class="top_wood"  src="image/fifth/wood_1.jpg">
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-2" style="text-align: left;">
            <img class="top_wood"  src="image/fifth/wood_2.jpg">
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3" style="text-align: center; ">
            <img class="top_wood" src="image/fifth/wood_3.jpg">
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-2" style="text-align: right; ">
            <img class="top_wood" src="image/fifth/wood_4.jpg">
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3" style="text-align: right; ">
            <img class="top_wood"  src="image/fifth/wood_5.jpg">
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Бутстрап стоковый стоит - ничего в нем не менял. Не могу понять как можно отцентровать центральный блок. И через что надписи делать.

Comment: задать для цетрального .col-md-4, а на остальных .col-md-2

Comment: вариант без бутстрапа - https://jsfiddle.net/1ddvkyzt/